# Node.js Cluster: Managing Workers

Tags: node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing, worker

we're diving deeper in Node.js architecture, to achieve fully understanding, how to scale our application. 
Clear solution is cluster usage https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html. Everything seems to be fine, apart of workers management description:

> Node.js does not automatically manage the number of workers for you, however. It is your responsibility to manage the worker pool for your application's needs.

I was searching, how to really manage the workers, but most solutions, says:

> Start so many workers as you've got cores.

But I would like to dynamically scale up or down my workers count, depending on current load on server. So if there is load on server and queue is getting longer,  I would like to start next worker. In another way, when there isn't so much load, I would like to shut down workers (and leave f.e. minimum 2 of them).

The ideal place, will be for me Master Process queue, and event when new Request is coming to Master Process. On this place we can decide if we need next worker.

Do you have any solution or experience with managing workers from Master Thread in Cluster? Starting and killing them dynamically?

Regards,

Radek

Answer (score 0):

following code will help you to understand to create cluster on request basis.

this program will genrate new cluster in every 10 request.

Note: you need to open http://localhost:8000/ and refresh the page for increasing request.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var numReqs = 0;
var initialRequest = 10;
var maxcluster = 10;
var totalcluster = 2;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var worker = cluster.fork();
    console.log('cluster master');
    worker.on('message', function(msg) {
      if (msg.cmd && msg.cmd == 'notifyRequest') {
        numReqs++;
      }
    });
  }

  setInterval(function() {
    console.log("numReqs =", numReqs);
    isNeedWorker(numReqs) && cluster.fork();
  }, 1000);
} else {
  console.log('cluster one initilize');
  // Worker processes have a http server.
  http.Server(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("hello world\n");
    // Send message to master process
    process.send({ cmd: 'notifyRequest' });
  }).listen(8000);
}

function isNeedWorker(numReqs) {
  if( numReqs >= initialRequest && totalcluster < numCPUs ) {
    initialRequest = initialRequest + 10;
    totalcluster = totalcluster + 1;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To manually manage your workers, you need a messaging layer to facilitate inter process communication. With IPC master and worker can communicate effectively, by default and architecture stand point this behavior is already implemented in the process module native. However i find the native implementation not flexible or robust enough to handle horizontal scaling due to network requests.

One obvious solution Redis as a message broker to facilitate this method of master and slave communication. However this solution also as its faults , which is context latency, directly linked to command and reply.

Further research led me to RabbitMQ,great fit for distributing time-consuming tasks among multiple workers.The main idea behind Work Queues (aka: Task Queues) is to avoid doing a resource-intensive task immediately and having to wait for it to complete. Instead we schedule the task to be done later. We encapsulate a task as a message and send it to the queue. A worker process running in the background will pop the tasks and eventually execute the job. When you run many workers the tasks will be shared between them.

To  implement a robust server , read this link , it may give some insights. [Link](http://www.journaldev.com/7462/node-js-architecture-single-threaded-event-loop)